Shopping cart Issue (incrementing and decrementing product amount)
I'm building a shopping cart and i encountered a problem decrementing products from the array.
this cart takes in a product, if a product already exist, increment its amount.
for decrementing if the item amount is ===1, add to cart.
This is my Add to cart function
addToCart(product:Product){
  const ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartList') || '[]') as Product[] | null;

  let productAlreadyInCart = false;
  // Check if the product is already in the cart
  for (let item of this.cartItemList) {
    if (item.name === product.name) {
      // If the product is already in the cart, increment its amount and price
      item.amount ++
      item.price = product.price * item.amount;
      productAlreadyInCart = true;
      localStorage.setItem('cartList', JSON.stringify(ls))
      console.log(this.total,'item amount incremented')
      break; // No need to continue looping once found
      // console.log(this.total);
    }

  }
  // If the product is not in the cart, add it
  if(!productAlreadyInCart) {
    // get list of produts in local storage and append
    const newData = this.cartItemList.push({ ...product, amount: 1 });
    localStorage.setItem('cartList', JSON.stringify(newData))
    console.log('item added successfully')
  }
  // Update total
  this.getTotal();
  console.log(this.total, 'new item');
}

and i decrement, remove it from the array, otherwise just decrement the amount
now the incrementing works, Increment
incrementQuantity(product:Product){
  console.log('item amount decremented', product)
  // confirm if item exist
  let item = this.cartItemList.find(item => item.name === product.name)
  if(item){
    item.amount +=1
    item.price += product.price
  }
  this.getTotal();
}

my issue now is the decrementing.
to understand the issue better i will create a use case, however you can skip and just look at the code snippets in my solution attempts
decrement
(Use case)
we wont touch on the incrementing, again, it works
for the decrement however, imagine we have a vase in our cart at $100,
product:Product[] =[{
    name: 'vase',
    price: 100,
    description:'ceramic',
    image: '../assets/vase.png',
    BlackFridaySale: true,
    amount: 0 //when we add an item the amount is set to 1
}]

when we increment to 3 vases, the price updates to 300$, however when i decrement, instead of remove 100 dollars which is the price of one, it removes the whole $300 and sets the price to 0
decremnetQuantity(product: Product){
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cartItemList.length; i++) {
    const item = this.cartItemList[i];
    if (item.name === product.name) {
      if (item.amount === 1) {
        this.total -= item.price;
        this.cartItemList.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        item.amount--;
        item.price -= product.price;
      }
      // this.updateCart();
      this.getTotal();
      break;
    }
  }
}

it seems i am somehow editing the same instance of my items in the array and i don't know where its coming from.
i tried a for loop in the decrement logic, I'll also put the rest of the important snippets so i don't leave any gray area.
I'd appreciate some insight

Why are you changing this.total when there was only one of the item in the cart, but if it was more, you leave this.total completely alone?

@CBroe the this.total function just gives me a accumulation of the price of items in the array, if there's only one, then return me the price of it and subsequent products added
Hope this helps

Step through your code and log every step of the way.
